# Typo in help: s/signpoint/signpost

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-questions, help-center

As pointed out [in this recent question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417385/why-would-a-question-be-deleted-if-its-on-topic-and-not-extremely-low-quality), the [help page about deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions) contains a weird non-word.

> Over time, closed questions that are not useful as **signpoints** to other questions may also be removed, as well as questions which have no significant activity over a very long period after being asked.

(Emphasis mine.)

Presumably, it should say "signposts"; this is the term used in a similar context e.g. on the [help page about duplicates.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: Oddly, it appears to have been that way for some time [at least since 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107432/1099857)

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I'm not a big fan of the "signpost" term either; I don't think it's very understandable to many people for whom English is a foreign language.

Comment: "Signpost" was used in [a 2013 blogpost](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/06/25/the-war-of-the-closes/), but what is the origin of the term (in a Stack Overflow context)? An older blog post?

Comment: The [earliest hit in the SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=20686278#20686278) is from 2014, so that blog post may well be where it originated.

Comment: @tripleee I really do not know about that. "signpost" is a pretty basic vocabulary word (I may be biased as I learned British English). I guess we could go for "pole" for maximum confusion :) "It is not a good pole to the duplicate target!"

Comment: If it's not part of your vocabulary, the word is not very transparent, though image search should quickly give you the correct idea. "Road sign" is less accurate, but perhaps more likely to have been taught in elementary school English.

Comment: @tripleee yeah, might be easier to grasp (although I am not a big fan of optimising for people who do not look new words up in a basic google search), but feels a bit... clunky, I guess? "It is a good road sign for..." kinda feels off. "pointer", maybe?

Comment: No need for a metaphor here - "duplicate questions which do not make the original question easier to find".

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1375/)

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine if we change it to pointer, I can't wait for the first meta post complaining that a duplicate target got deleted and SO threw a NullPointerException :)

Comment: @DanielWiddis that's actually a nice idea for an easter egg :) I vote for "pointer"!

Comment: I think you can just use "references" or "pointers" or "links" as in ***Over time, closed questions that are not useful as references to other questions may also be removed***.  The word "reference" is already used a few other places in the Help Center such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, you are right. "[Signpost](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/signpost)" is a word (and one already used elsewhere in our guidance); "signpoint" is not.

That phrasing has apparently been on the `/help/deleted-questions` page of the help center (network-wide) since it was created – and even before that, when the function of the help center was served by a single `/faq` page.

I've now changed "signpoint" to "signpost" in that sentence, and added a link to the help center page about duplicates (`/help/duplicates`). I've also made a number of other updates and changes to the `/help/deleted-questions` page (as well as the corresponding page about deleted answers, located at `/help/deleted-answers` - [located here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)).

Comment: Thanks! For us curious sticklers, is there a place where we can see a diff?

Comment: I notice that the page about deleted answers talks about questions in the (presumably copy/pasted) paragraph about spam and rude flags.

Comment: There's also a formatting error where the markdown bleeds through `[site moderators][11]`; I'm guessing link 11 is missing or malformed.

Comment: @tripleee: The markdown issue on `/help/deleted-answers`? Ah yeah, that's probably because I copied a bit from `/help/deleted-questions` and forgot to fix the link labeling. Should be fixed now. I also fixed the phrasing of both pages in the rude/abusive and spam flags line to refer to "posts" in general.

Comment: As for the revision history, I think only CMs (and maybe MSE mods?) can view it... Probably not interesting enough for me to paste the full thing somewhere, though. Mostly it comes down to updating a few details that have changed in the past decade, as well as adding a few relevant links to other help center pages and the occasional MSE post. (And copying some relevant info from the deleted-questions page to the deleted-answers page as well.)